# Multiper Connectivity Versus Play Game Services

Tags: android, ios, google-play-games, multipeer-connectivity

I am currently developing an application that exchanges small chunks of data between iOS devices. Eventually, my plan is to release an Android version of the application. It seems as if it may be overkill to use Google Play Game Services on iOS for data exchange with Multipeer Connectivity available however it may be necessary to achieve multi-platform data exchange. Am I better off implementing completely separate iterations of the iOS and Android applications using Multipeer Connectivity and Google Game Services respectively or should I use Google Game Services for both? Also, it would be appreciated if someone could detail the performance differences between the two frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more options than using MPC or GPGS. As Columbo said, you can use Bluetooth and WiFi Direct directly on Android. It's a long and bumpy way because it's not as stable on Android as it is on iOS. There are also other frameworks out there that try to mitigate the issues.

Disclaimer: I work for Uepaa, developing p2pkit for Android and iOS.

Comment: What framework(s) would you recommend for such a task?

Comment: @Alex You can can check out http://p2pkit.io/, http://www.intromi.co/ and http://underdark.io/

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Multipeer is an iOS technology that allows for direct communication between **nearby** iOS devices. This can use Adhoc/Direct WiFi, Bluetooth or connect two devices which are on the same WiFi router.

Google Play Games Services allows for communication between devices **across the internet**.

The two technologies are not really comparable because they solve different problems. If you need communication across the internet on iOS, then perhaps you need to be evaluating Game Center instead of Multipeer. If you need local communication, then perhaps you should investigate Android's bluetooth and WiFi Direct capabilities.

Comment: I have actually used both Multipeer Connectivity(MPC) before and the Google's nearby Messages API. Despite this, Google's nearby message API doesn't allow for connecting to specific peers. If you publish an event, everyone sees it. Specifically from Google Play Game Services, Real Time Multiplayer Matches allows users to connect like in MPC in that you can connect to peers via hosts and peers and send messages directly [link]https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use GPGS to achieve direct wireless communication in the same way that you can with Multipeer.

When they talk about sending data in a 'room' in that Google Play Games Services link, the 'room' is metaphor for the fully-connected set of devices that are linked across the internet. 

The matchmaking options for choosing who to add to a room are a bit limited too. You can either directly invite google+ friends, or you can join random matches. Neither of which sound too suitable for your needs.

Comment: After looking through some of the frameworks supplied by google, it appears that Play Game Services includes the Nearby Messages API. For that API, Google states, "Nearby uses a combination of Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, Wi-Fi and near-ultrasonic audio to communicate a unique-in-time pairing code between devices."